# Is there an API call to check what account the scheduled queries in bigquery are running under?

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to test the datatransfer APIs for scheduled queries. I updated the transfer config with a service account. How do i validate that the config is updated with the service account(via API)

Comment: do you have any code example? please check [ask]

Comment: Hi! please provide a code, what language do you want to use to check this?